# Find the sup of this set with condition $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: inequality

let $x,y,z>0$,and such $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$,show that  $$\min{((x-y)^2,(y-z)^2,(z-x)^2)}< \dfrac{1}{5}$$and show that $\dfrac{1}{5}$ is best constant. If it is not possible to find the maximal value, is it possible to give some reasonable upper bound?

Comment: Which sup of which mean.

Comment: The min is zero.

Comment: When $x = y = z$, or $x,y,z = \frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ the differences between them is $0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Do you know how to optimize the minimum of a set of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Say $x\le y \le z$. So we have to show that at least one of the differences $y-x$, $z-y$ is  $<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. Assume not. Then 
$x>0$, $y >\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, $z > \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$, hence their sum of squares is larger than $1$. One can easily see that the constant $1/5$ cannot be decreased, by using $(x,y,z)$ close to the triplet $(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$.

Answer (score -1):

The best upper bound is $1/5$, and is achieved at six points on the sphere. These points have coordinates being the six permutations of $2/\sqrt{5},1/\sqrt{5},0$

To solve this, notice that given a point $P(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $(x_0-y_0)^2$ is the square of the distance of point $P$ to the plane $x-y=0$, and similarly for $(y_0-z_0)^2$, $(z_0-x_0)^2$. So to maximize $\min\{(x_0-y_0)^2 ,(y_0-z_0)^2,(z_0-x_0)^2\}$, you should find a point on the sphere that's simultaneously far away from all these three planes.

If you imagine looking down at the sphere from the point $(1,1,1)$, you'll see the three planes cutting the sphere at $60$ degrees angle between them. Then it's clear from geometry which points should maximize $\min\{(x_0-y_0)^2 ,(y_0-z_0)^2,(z_0-x_0)^2\}$

Answer (score -1):

Let $x\geq y\geq z$.

1. $x-y\geq y-z$.

We need to prove that $$(y-z)^2\leq\frac{1}{5}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$ or
$$x^2\geq2(2y-z)(y-2z),$$
which is true for $y\leq 2z$.

Let $y\geq2z$.

Hence, since $x\geq2y-z$, it's enough to prove that $$x\geq2(y-2z)$$ or
$$x-2y+4z\geq0,$$
which is true because $x-2y+z\geq0$.

2. $x-y\leq y-z$.

We need to prove that:
$$(x-y)^2\leq\frac{1}{5}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$ or
$$z^2\geq2(2x-y)(x-2y),$$
which is obvious because $x-2y\leq-z<0$.

The equality "occurs" for $z\rightarrow0^+$ and $x-y=y$, which says that the equality does not occur

and after solving the system $x^2+y^2=1$, $x=2y$ we get that $\frac{1}{5}$ is indeed our $\sup$.

Done!